# Why is Blend4web's 'pick_object' giving a 'null' value?

Tags: scripting, blend4web

```
var x = m_mouse.get_coords_x(e);
var y = m_mouse.get_coords_y(e);

var obj = m_scenes.pick_object(x, y);   
console.log(obj);
```

This gives a `null` value and it does not get the object inside the mouse's 'x' and 'y' coordinates.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the object must have **Selectable** option enabled in its Blender settings.